# Furnace wiring diagram: HUM 120 VAC or 24 VAC can be used

Tags: electrical, hvac, furnace, humidifier

On my furnace wiring diagram located on the inner cover, it states that the HUM dry contact terminals can use either 120v or 24v. How is this possible? There is no reference to how to switch this.

Would it require switching the relay output lines somehow? If so where would the power source come from? I see no reference to spare 120v or 24v terminals to feed the relay.

The furnace is a Trane S9X2

[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo of the diagram itself please?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel sure, just edited the post

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“dry contact terminals” mean a connection that gets closed/opened (usually by a relay). No power is provided by the contacts - it’s just a switch. The power comes from the device being controlled.

It’s labeled 24/120 VAC because those are common (24 if controlling another device’s relay, 120 if controlling it directly) and the relay provided in your furnace is rated to switch both. The contacts would also handle any other voltage between those two, but you’re not likely to encounter anything else.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. So essentially it’s just a way for the furnace to control a third party power source. Do you see any power source for a humidifier on there anywhere? I thought most furnaces today provided a 120v terminal for this purpose